# SQL Stored Procedure Insert value based on id

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I want to run a stored procedure that uses the self generated ID to populate a value in another column but in the same row.

EX:

Table: `ID`, `Reference`

`ID` is auto number, `Reference` is a `VARCHAR` made of `ID-CURRENTDATE`.

Thus if the ID is 230, for the insert statement, the Ref should be `230-20130225`.

Is this possible, and how can I achieve this?

Comment: This seems to call for a trigger. But to get a more or less specific suggestion, you should probably clarify what SQL product you are using.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like stored procedures are highly vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Sorry, I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on sql-server, you could do this with a `computed column`.

```
create table myTable ( 
    id int identity (1,1) not null,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    recordDate date default getdate(),
    reference  as ((convert(varchar,[id1],(0)) + '-') + convert(varchar,recordDate,(112)))
)
```

And then your insert would be like (or you can enter a recordDate)

```
insert into myTable (name)
values ('xyz')
```

If you can't alter the table then try (in a stored procedure);

```
declare @recordId int
insert into myTable (name)
values ('xyz')

select @recordId = scope_identity()

update myTable set reference = convert(varchar, @recordId) + '-' +  
                               convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)
where id = @recordId
```